# Vbscript in C #

Tags: c#, vbscript

I want to disable or enable users in OS and ADAM. To achieve this i am using the below script to enable a user at the OS level. I want to run this script within the C # code and I do not want to call this vb script file from c# code. Is there a way to embed this vbscript within c # code ?

```vb
strComputer = "."

' Specify local user name.
strUser = "new"

' Bind to local user account on the computer.
Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/" & strUser & ",user")

' Enable the user.
objUser.AccountDisabled = True
objUser.SetInfo
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot parse your question. Please ask someone with good English to help you rewrite it for clarity.

Comment: Write it to a batch file and use the shell to execute it.

Comment: @asawyer: Taken from the question "**I do not want to call this vb script file from c# code**"

Comment: @BinaryWorrier True, but it's also the easiest way to accomplish the goal, and the questioner did not specify any concrete reason why this option is eliminated other then "i dont want to".

Comment: What version of C#/Visual Studio are you using? This can be done painlessly in C# 4 (which ships with VS2010).

Comment: I am using C# version 3. I will update it to version 4. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C# 4 (or later) you can rather painlessly convert the calls to C#

```
void EnableUser(string computer, string user)
{
    var objectName = "WinNT://" + computer + "/" + user + ",user";
    dynamic objUser = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(objectName));
    // Enable the user.
    objUser.AccountDisabled = true;
    objUser.SetInfo();
}
```

Should work

Comment: @L.B: Thanks, that was rather dumb of me

Comment: You're welcome mate . . . How about marking it as correct? Giving it a +1? All optional of course, and I don't do it for the rep . . . just saying is all . . . .